# Reshape list of lists based on position of the element

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists that looks like this;

```
[[4, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
```

Which is the most efficient way to get 3 lists from the above list based on the position of the element?

Result:

```
[4,0,0,1,2]
[0,0,1,1,0]
[1,1,2,0,0]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
>>> lst = [[4, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
[[4, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

Placing `*` before `lst` unpacks the list into arguments for the `zip` function.  In this case:

```
zip(*lst)
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
zip([4, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0])
```

`zip` then zips these lists together by returning an iterator of tuples where the n-th tuple contains the n-th item from each of the lists.  In this case, it returns:<sup>1</sup>

```
>>> list(zip(*lst))
[(4, 0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
>>>
```

Finally, the list comprehension converts these tuples into lists and collects them into a new list.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>You need to call `list()` on `zip(*lst)` to view its items because `zip` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) in Python 3.x.</sub>

Comment: This'll get a +1 from me if you say something about the `*` before `lst` and maybe a sentence about `zip` generally.

Comment: @LondonRob - Better? :)